# CSS not being applied when using with React, Typescript and typescript-plugin-css-modules

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have a setup with React and Typescript and I am trying to import and use CSS modules. I have installed the `typescript-plugin-css-modules` and changed the `tsconfig.json` by adding `"plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }]`. Also, I have a `Global.d.ts` that includes

```
declare module "*.module.css" {
  const classes: { [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
```

This is my `webpack.config.js`

```
{
   test: /\.css$/,
   use: [
      "style-loader",
      {
         loader: "css-loader",
         options: {
             modules: true,
         },
      },],
},
```

Now the import inside the React components works but they are not being applied/rendered.

```
import styles from "./mystyle.module.css"
<span className={styles.StyledSpan}>text</span>
```

What can I be missing in this configuration?

Comment: I think your component file name should be the same as the css module file for instance Button.js => Button.module.css maybe this helps

Comment: @SED I just tried that, I didn't resolve the problem. Also, I am trying to do console.log(styles) to see if I can see the CSS and I get `undefined`

Comment: looks like you have configured properly. Do you have a minimal reproducible repo anyway?

Comment: @tmhao2005 No, I don't have it at the moment. Can you let me know where I can do that? Taking into account that it supports React and Typescript?

Comment: here’s the link that how to do https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example